# Formula for finding vacancy percentage by month from check-in and check-out dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on one spreadsheet. I want to find out total nights (month wise) from check-in and check-out date, Vacancy % (month wise), and Avg Night rate (month wise).

I've created simple format with google spreadsheet. Please check this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AZfpAic0PT3phLiedZh7I43pu6A3L9w4RhTchKtA0zw/edit#gid=0

In short, need to fill up "??" fields.

Comment: Sorry, Stack overflow suggested that tag that's why.. Now, I've removed that.

Comment: I'm thinking that vacancy % = (number of rooms)*(number of days in month)-(total nights occupied in month) / (number of rooms) * (number of days in month) multiplied by 100. However we don't know the number of rooms?

Comment: There is only one room. We need vacancy% month wise..

Comment: Ah, I see. It wasn't obvious from a quick look at the data because the second and third bookings are 21/11-24/11 and 20/11-30/11 i.e. they overlap.

Comment: I have another solution and will post it tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sample data is located at `C6:H63` *(adjust as needed)*
*Note: Included three records at the beginning to show summaries for next year as well as error for monthly occupancy beyond monthly capacity.*

This solution requires:

- Two Working cells to provide flexibility and space for growth:

**Capacity (rooms)** : Located at `E4`; used to hold total numbers of rooms *(actually is one, hopefully the business will growth)*.

**Year** : Year of the first period in Data, used to update header of *“Monthly Allocation”, “Monthly Summary”*. Located at `K4`

**Total Nights** : Modification of the formula to calculate Total Nights in column `E` in order to validated `Check In` & `Check Out` dates. Enter this formula in `E7` and copy till last record:

```
=ISNUMBER( C7 ) * ISNUMBER( D7 ) * ( $D7 > $C7 ) * SUM( $D7, - $C7 )
```

**The Results Range includes two areas** *(see Fig. 1)*

1. **Monthly Allocation** : located at `J6:V63`

   **Header** : Update `Number Format` for range `J6:X6` as `mmm-yy` and `Y6` as `mmm dd, yyyy`. Used to update the header of this area. Enter this formula in `J6`

   ```
   =DATE( $K$4, 1, 1 )
   ```

   And this formula in `K6` and copy to `L6:X6`

   ```
   = 1 + EOMONTH( J6, 0 )
   ```

   Then enter this formula in `Y6`

   ```
   =EOMONTH(X6,0)
   ```

   **Body** : To allocate monthly occupancy enter this formula in `J7` and copy till last record then copy to other months `K7:X63`

   ```
   =IFERROR( IF( $E7 = 0, "", CHOOSE( 1
   + ( 1 + EOMONTH( $C7, -1 ) = J$6 ) * 1
   + AND( 1 + EOMONTH( $C7, -1 ) < J$6, 1 + EOMONTH( $D7, -1 ) > J$6 ) * 2
   + ( 1 + EOMONTH( $D7, -1 ) = J$6 ) * 3,
   "",
   1 + DAYS( EOMONTH( J$6, 0 ), $C7 ),
   1 + DAYS( EOMONTH( J$6, 0 ), J$6 ),
   DAYS( $D7, J$6 ),
   SUM( $D7, - $C7 ) ) ),
   "" )
   ```
2. **Monthly Summary** : located at `I65:Y67`

   **Total Nights** : Enter this formula in `J67 and copy till`Y67`

   ```
   =SUM( Y$7:Y$63 )
   ```

   **Vacancy %** : Enter this formula in `J65` and copy till `Y65`. This formula also validates the total occupancy against total capacity and returns `!Err` if `occupancy > capacity` *(see `Dec-15` in fig. 2)*.

   ```
   =IF( J$67 > ( ( 1 + DAYS( EOMONTH( J$6, 0 ), J$6 ) ) * $E$4 ), "!Err",
   1 - J$67 / ( ( 1 + DAYS( EOMONTH( J$6, 0 ), J$6 ) ) * $E$4 ) )
   ```

   **Avg Nightly Rate** : Enter this formula in `J66` and copy till `X66`

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT( J$7:J$63, $H$7:$H$63 )
   ```

   and enter this formula in `Y66`

   ```
   = 1 - $Y$67 / ( ( 1 + DAYS( $Y$6, $J$6 ) ) * $E$4 )
   ```

[image]

*Fig. 1*

[image]

*Fig. 2*

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help, Can you please share your sample spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate the days in each visit to the right month even when the visit is split over two months. I'm going to start by adding 12 helper columns with headers 1-12 (i.e. one per month) in columns I to T and use the following formula starting from I2 to find how many days to put in each month for each visit:-

```
=MAX(MIN(EOMONTH(DATE(2015,I$1,1),0)+1,$D2)-MAX(DATE(2015,I$1,1),$C2),0)
```

Then to get the vacancy percentage per month starting in V7 and pulled across:-

```
=(DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2015,I$1,1),0))-SUM(I2:I55))*100/DAY(EOMONTH(DATE(2015,I$1,1),0))
```

To get the average room rate per month starting in V8 and pulled across:-

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(SUM(I2:I55*$H2:$H55)/SUM(I2:I55),""))
```

And to get the total number of nights per month starting in V9 and pulled across:-

```
=sum(I2:I55)
```

Helper columns:-

[image]

Results:-

[image]

Comment: Hey Tom,

Thanks for your help, Can you please share your sample spreadsheets?

Comment: Here's the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vt5DYjQjcloeiWSfh7XySY__dx8RDoyxpJDMuZueD2g/edit?usp=sharing